# How to build a PHP image uploader while file inputs value cannot be set dynamically?

Tags: javascript, php, html, file-upload, dynamic

I keep trying to build a dynamic image uploader where I have a pair of inputs: one file and a text input (for custom name). Additional pairs can be added by a click of a button (done via javascript).

```
@foreach($table ? json_decode($table->textures, true) : [] as $texture_name => $texture_img_name)
  <div class="row">
    <div>
      <h3>Texture name</h3>
      <input type="text" name="texture_names[]" value="{{$texture_name}}">
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>Picture</h3>
      <div>
        <img src="/storage/img/tables/{{$table->id . '/textures/' . $texture_img_name}}" alt="">
        <input type="hidden" name="texture_img_names[]" class="texture_img_name" value="{{$texture_img_name}}">
        <input type="file" name="texture_img_files[]" onchange="copyImgName(this)" value="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
@endforeach
```

js:

```
function addTextureField(elt){
      var parent = elt.parentNode.querySelector('.inner');
      var template =
      `<div class="row">
    <div>
      <h3>Texture name</h3>
      <input type="text" name="texture_names[]" value="{{$texture_name}}">
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>Picture</h3>
      <div>
        <img src="/storage/img/tables/{{$table->id . '/textures/' . $texture_img_name}}" alt="">
        <input type="hidden" name="texture_img_names[]" class="texture_img_name" value="{{$texture_img_name}}">
        <input type="file" name="texture_img_files[]" onchange="copyImgName(this)" value="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>`;

      parent.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', template);
    }

function copyImgName(input){
      input.parentNode.querySelector('.texture_img_name').value = input.files[0].name;
    }
```

Each time the uploads happen, I replace the file names (JSON object) in the database with the new names.

The issue I face is when the user tries to modify the list of uploaded images, say he changes 1 image out of 3, now ideally I could just set the remaining file input's values to the name of the unchanged images, submit the form, and all the (new & old) names would go into the DB while the new image gets uploaded.

But as we know file inputs value attribute is read only, so as a work around (hack) I use a hidden input for holding existing image names and when an images gets changed, I use JS to switch the hidden input's value to the new name, which may not be the best idea.

I hope someone could give me some directions on what would be a better approach or solution for this scenario?

Thanks!

Comment: Uh... and what is your question?

Comment: What would be a better approach or solution for this scenario?

Comment: There is about a million billion options and tutorials with examples on how to upload files dynamically. [Using files from web applications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications) is possibly one of the better ones. While it does not answer your question(s) completely, it should help.

Comment: Thanks, the uploading part is straight forward, but there may be others facing this and got a better idea around here.